# Take first available item for every year in list

Tags: c#, date, time

I have a list with dates that I want to retrieve every first existing item for each year. The problem is that it doesn't always contain a item for the first of January. Below code gets everything for the moment but if a day is missing a whole year is not displayed.

```
foreach (var index in pModel.IndexData)
{
    if (index.Date.ConvertToDateTime().Day == 02 && index.Date.ConvertToDateTime().Month == 01)
         {
            yearlyIndex.Add(index);
         }
}
```

Example of how the dates can look.

- 2000-01-01
- 2000-02-03
- 2001-03-11... etc

How can i do so i always get the correct item? In this example I always want to get row1 and row3. I can make a loop with a bunch of if statements and add days month and years but I would like to deal with this problem with either linq or lambda.

Comment: Sounds like a `orderby` Date and `distinct` on year.

Comment: Order by date. Then group by year. Then just select the first item in each group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GroupBy()` the years, order and pick the oldest item per year.

```
List<DateTime> result = input.GroupBy(x => x.Year)
                             .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y).First()).ToList();
```

Sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/As0FBI

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is unnecessarily verbose if all you want is a list of min dates for each year.  The same result can be accomplished more efficiently by exchanging `OrderBy(y => y).First()` with just `.Min()`.

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.Year)
                  .Select(x => x.Min()).ToList();
```

If the date was a property of the list item type instead of the type itself, then the accepted answer would be the correct solution as long as that property was referenced in the `OrderBy` selector function.